# Segmented Control in Calculator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, math, uisegmentedcontrol

Im trying to make a Segmented Control that holds two values, but I'm having trouble making it. I want to multiply the input by whatever side is picked in the segmented view and displayed in the label, but I keep running into errors. Any help?

```
@IBOutlet var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var controller: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func convert(sender: UIButton) {
}






@IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject) {
    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
       result = number1 * 1
    }
    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        result = number1 * 5
    }



    let number1 = Double(input.text!)
    label.text = "\(result)"

}
```

Comment: "I keep running into errors" what errors? what is `result`? what is not working?

Comment: Introduce this errors to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you use "number1" before declaration?
Try this:

```
@IBOutlet var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var output: UILabel!
var result:Double! //fixed "cannot be applied to Double and Int." problem
@IBOutlet var controller: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func convert(sender: UIButton) {
}


@IBAction func change(sender: AnyObject) {
let number1 = Double(input.text!)
    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
       self.result = number1 * 1
    }
    if controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        self.result = number1 * 5
    }




    label.text = "\(result)"

}
```

Comment: I see what your saying. Now I've run into the issue where it says that a binary "*" cannot be applied to Double and Int. But I can't figure out how to correct that.

Comment: @WesleyBryant Just change var result:Int! to var result:Double! (: or if you prefer to show result as integer value change the "number1" to Int instead Double.